# Displaying fancy routes in cloudmade based service

Tags: javascript, api, gis, cloudmade

I look for a way to display a route in a fancy way using the Cloudmade service.

Currently, I can see computed routes like on this tutorial http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/web-maps-lite/examples/routing, but I look for a fancier way to do it -- without A and B tags, and with colors, etc.

Is this possible ?

Thanks for your help

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible unfortunately, the only way to do this is to use the [NavEngine API](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/navengine/documents) directly and process the JSON responses manually. But we will think about making the `CM.Directions` class more configurable in future releases, thanks!